# Scope problems with inherited non-template class (template base, non-template derived)

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a templated base class with non-templated derived classes. I have been following  umsl.edu/~subramaniana/templates8.html and http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ to do so.

```
template <class Type>
class Base {
protected:
    std::string line;
public:
    Base();
};

class DerivedA : public Base<T> {
    //error: 'T' was not declared in this scope
    //error: template argument 1 is invalid
public:
    DerivedA();
protected:
    std::list<std::string> A;
};
```

I think I am missing something fundamental about how this all works, but I can't seem to grasp it.

This is the full header and implementation:

http://ideone.com/H9NXdw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `template<typename T>` in class DerivedA declaration. Base is a template, you need to provide template parameter to it.

```
template<typename T> 
class DerivedA : public Base<T>
```

Or you could let DerivedA derive from a certain type of Base, for example:

```
 class DerivedA : public Base<int>
```

Comment: I am confused. The idea is for the class DerivedA to be a non-template class. I was under the impression from http://www.umsl.edu/~subramaniana/templates8.html that I was not supposed to do that if I wanted a non-template derived class.

Comment: the link provides the concepts of `template base, nontemplate derive`, you should apply to my second sample in my answer. Think about it, where is T come from?